# How to get the value of an input without quotes in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

What I'm working with is this:

```js
function calc() {
  document.getElementById('Output').innerHTML =
    document.getElementById('CalcInput').value;
}
```

```html
<div id="Output"></div>
<input type="text" id="CalcInput" value="2*10" />
<button onclick="calc()">
  Enter
</button>
```

For some reason, the function returns '2 * 5' as opposed to '10', which is what I want it to return. how can I get the value without the quotes?

Comment: Note that the linked duplicate shows how to execute user input as code, but bear in mind that this should only ever be used either for contrived purely academic examples like this one or when you *really absolutely know what you're doing*.  Allowing a user to write and execute their own code is historically a dangerous habit to get into.

Comment: What would you expect your code to return from the input "the value of the definite integral from 0 to π of sin(x) with respect to x"?

Answer (score 1):

By using eval function you can evaluate your result !

```
 function calc() {
    document.getElementById('Output').innerHTML =
     eval(document.getElementById('CalcInput').value);
}
```